# What API permission is needed when enabling User assignment required? in Azure AD Enterprise application

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

If in Azure portal, I set `Enterprise applications > Properties > User assignment required?` to `No`, then authentication works as expected. However, if I turned it on, users get error `Application needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant`. I understand that I need to add an API permission to my app, but what is it?

Interestingly, if a user has signed in into the app before, then they are not affected when turning the option on. Only users who have never use it are affected

**Edit**: To clarify, I already have App roles created. Users without app roles can't sign in, as expected. Users WITH app roles who sign in for the first time after the the option turned to Yes get the above error

Comment: Hi, I need to talk to the admin about this, it will take a while

Comment: Hi, any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I reproduce your issue with the request URL below, the scope also could be another one, e.g. `https://storage.azure.com/.default`, which has been added in the `API permissions` of the AD App.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant0id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

If the `User assignment required` is set to `Yes`, I notice it will not promote the user to consent the permissions. (e.g. `user_impersonation` in the `Azure Service Management` API.)

To fix the issue, we need the admin consent to the App, just navigate to the `API permissions`, click the `Grant the admin consent for xxx` button, then it will work fine.

[image]